# Using var to declare variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm struggling with (what I believe to be) a scoping issue.  Here's a sample of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var counter = 0;

function scrollTweets() {
    counter ++;
    // rest of code
}

...

)}; // end of document ready
```

When I look up the variable `counter` in Chrome's Javascript console it returns "ReferencedError".  However, when I remove `var` from the code above and type `counter` into the console, it returns the value.  Why is this?

I think understanding this simple concept would allow me to tackle issues that seem to pop up during development.  Is it just a scoping issue on Chrome's part?  Am I needlessly wrapping everything in the `$(document).ready` "function"?

Comment: Don't make it global! If you want to inspect `counter`, then set a breakpoint in the code. This will allow you to examine the current state of the variables in the various levels of closure. Or just log the value using `console.log()`.

Comment: thanks @Ӫ_._Ӫ ...that's a good technique!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `var` locks the variable `counter` into whatever the lexical scope is -- which means its available in the current block, method, whatever, and can be attached to closed-in scopes (ie. closures), like you are doing with `scrollTweets`.  So `counter` is only available in the `ready` callback and anything that has a closure around it, which is why you can't access it from your console.

When you take the `var` away, `counter` is effectively global, which is why you can access it in that case.

Answer (score 5):

When you don't use `var` to set the scope of the variable, it automatically becomes a global variable, inside the global scope. That's why it is visible in the Chrome console.

As a note, I'm by no means implying you should make the variable global. In fact that's almost always a bad idea! Capturing the variable in the context of the scope where it's used is the right thing to do. If the Chrome console can't handle that you just need a better debugger. Firebug for Javascript does a wonderful job at handling scope - even clojures!

Comment: @pruett, just to avoid any confusion, Firebug is only available for Firefox. But since it's a very powerful debugger it might be worth your while to use FF as your debugging browser..